# "xvalue has identity", why i can't cout it addreess

Tags: c++, c++11

[here](http://www.stroustrup.com/terminology.pdf) figure out

1. "has identity": address, a pointer, the user can determine whether two copies are identical.
2. xvalue: has identity and can be moved from (e.g. the result of casting an lvalue to a rvalue reference.

[here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#xvalue) figure out

The following expressions are xvalue expressions:
3. a.m, the member of object expression, where a is an rvalue and m is a non-static data member of non-reference type;

[here](https://riptutorial.com/cplusplus/example/2604/xvalue#example) give an example

```
struct X { int n; };

X{4};                // prvalue: does not have an identity

X{4}.n;              // xvalue: does have an identity and denotes resources
                     // that can be reused
```

but when i try to use `&` to `cout` the address of `X{4}.n`, the compiler deny to compile.

```
cout << &X{4}.n << endl;    // error C2102:  '&' requires l-value
```

does this mean i can never get an xvalue's address?

Comment: According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#rvalue , address of an rvalue may not be taken. Since xvalue belongs to rvalue, you may not take its address.

Comment: X{4}; expression is not actually a prvalue: "any expression that designates a temporary object, after temporary materialization" (cppref) is an xvalue. The expression designates a temporary object which is constructed and destructed in the expression it is declared, thus an xvalue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here’s what the standard says: [[expr.unary.op]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.unary.op#3)

> The result of the unary `&` operator is a pointer to its operand.
>   **The operand shall be an lvalue or a *qualified-id*.**

So no, you can’t take the address of an rvalue using the `&` operator.